# Removing new line character from Resultset (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have ResultSet that contains information as below -

```
[<div id="Description">\n    This is the content example.\n\r\nThese characters I need to remove from complete string.\n\r\nI tried strip,lstrip,rstrip and replace.\n\r\nBut for these I found the Attributeerror: resultset object has no attribute 'strip'(lstrip/rstrip/replace).\n</div>]
```

I retrieved it with:

```
webPage=urllib2.urlopen(GivenUrl)
soup=BeautifulSoup(webPage,"html.parser")
soupResultSet=soup.findAll('div',id='Description') #This result set contains the above information.
```

I am using python 2.7.12.

The original HTML:

```
<div id="Description">
    This is the content example.
These characters I need to remove from complete string.
I tried strip,lstrip,rstrip and replace.
But for these I found the Attributeerror: resultset object has no attribute 'strip'(lstrip/rstrip/replace).
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultSet` is a simple `list` subclass. `str.strip()` does not exist on lists, nor on the `div` element.

Get the *text* from each element, you can use the [`Tag.get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), which supports stripping directly:

```
[tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in soup.find_all('div', id='Description')]
```

Since you appear to be looking for a `<div>` with an `id` attribute, there should be only *one* such element. In that case, rather than use `soup.find_all()`, you should be using `soup.find()` and just get that one element rather than a list:

```
soup.find('div', id='Description').get_text(strip=True)
```

This gives you *one* `str` object, with whitespace removed from the start and end. You can further process this if you need to remove all newlines from the middle of the string too.

Comment: hi Pieters thanks for your reply. First method suggested by you is working good for me but the output is string. I want the ouput as a ResultSet, because I will append the output in list and then I will create Data Frame. Any suggestion please.

Comment: @Varun just put the string back in a list then.

Comment: Hi Pieters.. I tried the below code.. cleaned_soup=[tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in soup.findAll('div',id='Description')] cleaned_soup=BeautifulSoup(cleaned_soup,"html.parser") .. This is creating list of all the characters but I want the output(complete paragraph) as a single list. Thank you again for your quick reply..

Comment: @Varun why are you passing the list to `BeautifulSoup` again? The first part already gives you the list you wanted.

Comment: I am novice in Python and this is my code I am writing; so there might some ambiguity. I tried both one by one but I am getting same result. Below is the complete code and the corresponding output - 

cleaned_soup=[tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in soup.findAll('div',id='Description')] 
for desc in cleaned_soup:
 for row in desc:
  print len(row) #Output is- 1
  print cells    #Output is first character only- T
  break
My expectations is cells should print the complete paragraph.

Comment: @Varun drop the inner loop; each `desc` is a string, so each `row` is a single character from that string.